# How to make a words in label go down a line when it hits the edge of the window?

Tags: c#

After executing my code, it spits out a long output (which is what I want) but it sort of continues on going past the edge of the window. How do i get it to drop down a line  when it hits the edge?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `AutoSize` property of the label to `false`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx